# Calculate price between different dates

Tags: php, sql

Hi everyone I'm new and I need help about my booking hotel, I've this table:

```
id, idhotel, room, data_start, data_end, price
```

Now I need to calculate the total price  when samebody search the rooms between many days
I'm trying this query but the result is 0.

```
$query = "SELECT room, SUM(price) FROM price WHERE idhotel='".$_GET['id']."' BETWEEN 'data_start' AND 'data_end'  
ORDER BY room";
```

Can someone one help me?

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error there... or am I missing something? what is the field for "between" query?

Comment: What is `camera`? You don't have this in your table structure shown.

Comment: This is the result of query: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\booking camere\gethotel.php on line 143 (the line 143 is :while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){)

Comment: Sorry!! camera in english is room

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT idhotel, room, price, (DATEDIFF(data_end, data_start) * price) as total FROM rooms
```

For testing create next table and fill itselect * :

```
create table rooms (id int not null primary key auto_increment, idhotel int, room int, data_start date, data_end date, price int);

+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
| id | idhotel | room | data_start | data_end   | price |
+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |    1 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-12 |   100 |
|  2 |       1 |    1 | 2013-05-20 | 2013-05-20 |   100 |
+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Use next query for get total cost (modifed for prevent losing one day):

```
SELECT idhotel, room, price, ((DATEDIFF(data_end, data_start) + 1) * price) as total FROM rooms;
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+-------+-------+
| idhotel | room | price | total |
+---------+------+-------+-------+
|       1 |    1 |   100 |   400 |
|       1 |    1 |   100 |   100 |
+---------+------+-------+-------+
```

### Extend

If you want get room total sum for period, try use this code:

```
SELECT 
    idhotel, room, SUM(total) as total_sum 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        idhotel, 
        room,
        price, 
        (DATEDIFF(data_end, data_start) * price) as total 
    FROM 
        rooms
) as t 
GROUP BY 
    idhotel, room;
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+-----------+
| idhotel | room | total_sum |
+---------+------+-----------+
|       1 |    1 |       150 |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: In room I have the name ex: Twin not numbers maybe i this the problem

Comment: Low changes. More likly if you have another types for data_start and data_end

Comment: ok I posted here the code: pastebin.com/Cuwsnz91 samething is in italian linguage( like: camera is room, quantita' is quantity, prezzi is price, inizio is start, fine is end) table's mane is prezzi and I have id,idhotel,camera,default_price, inizio,fine - tnk guy for help me

Comment: Hi now it's works but I have a problem, It's found just last price ex:
from 2013-05-10 to 2013-05-11 the price is 100  and from 2013-05-11 to 2013-05-12 the price is 50 if I search the date from 2013-05-10 to 2013-05-12 result is 100 and not 150 can u help me please!!

Comment: Hi @Skugnizz, I extend answer

Comment: Tnk Again, the query doesen't works, it repor this problem: ,ischia,Afghanistan Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in \gethotel.php on line 162 -- the line 162 is while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ –

Comment: check how are you include params/variables into query. This query is SQL-well

Comment: Hi, tnk a lot for halp me, now it's work but i have a problem, this query sum all sample rooms exsample: I have hotel pino assigned a twin room date from june 01 to june 03 50,00 euro and the same room (twin) from june 04 to june 06 100 euro, if I search  the date from june 04 to june 05 just 1 day the query result 150 how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are probably looking for something like this

```
$date_start = $_GET['date_start'];
$date_end = $_GET['date_end'];
$hotel_id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT room, 
                 SUM(price) total
            FROM tablename
           WHERE data_start >= '$date_start' 
             AND date_end <= '$date_end'
             AND idhotel = $hotel_id
           GROUP BY room";
```

Comment: I have this problem:Notice: Undefined index: inizio in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\booking camere\gethotel.php on line 142

Notice: Undefined index: fine in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\booking camere\gethotel.php on line 143

Comment: @user2360728 It's hard to tell not being able to see your **actual** code. Post it (relevant parts) in your original question or if it's  too big (I see line 142 in the notice message) then post your code on pastebin.com or somewhere else and post the link to it.

Comment: ok I posted here the code: http://pastebin.com/Cuwsnz91 samething is in italian linguage( like: camera is room, quantita' is quantity, prezzi is price, inizio is start, fine is end) table's mane is prezzi and I have id,idhotel,camera,default_price, inizio,fine   - tnk guy for help me

Comment: @user2360728 The problem is you don't have parameters $_GET['inizio'] and $_GET['fine'] and you don't use them. I see you get dates from SESSION variables. So adjust your code accordingly.